# Apply code changes in module without removing static data

Tags: magento2, module, setup-upgrade

Every time I change some code when developing a module, I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. The problem is when executing this command, I end up with the deletion of the static front and admin css file as the command outputs this :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento>C:\xampp\php\php.exe bin/magento setup:upgrade
>       Cache cleared successfully
>       File system cleanup:
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Composer
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Magento
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Symfony
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/generation/Ves
>       The directory 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/_requirejs //all static files cleared
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/adminhtml //all static files cleared
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/deployed_version.txt //all static files cleared
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/frontend //all static files cleared
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/view_preprocessed/css
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/view_preprocessed/source
>       Updating modules:
>       ...

So I'm every time I have to execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to have a full functional front and esepcially backend (to create products, update categories, etc ...) .

My question is, is there any other method to apply code changes, or can I tell the script to ignore some directories (/pub/static/*) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

Checkout this link for further documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html#instgde-install-keep

But it would be better to run Magento 2 in developer mode. When you're in developer mode Magento automatically regenerates the pub/static folder when you delete it.

You can activate developer mode via the CLI:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

More details here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html